# How to iterate all argument passed to a task or function in SV?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

It is possible to iterate through all the argument that I passed to a system verilog task or function such as argv in c and @ARGV in Perl? Since I don't have any idea of how many argument that are going be passed into.

```
test("name2", 1,2,3);    // might pass more argument than this
```

```
task test(string signal, int tog1, int tog2, int tog3);
        $display("The value are: %s, %d and %d", signal, tog1, tog3) ;    //any way to just iterate through this?

endtask
```

Answer (score 3):

SystemVerilog does not hav this feature. Tasks and function call arguments get checked for matching prototypes at compilation.

Two alternatives I can think of:

1. If all arguments are the same datatype, as in your example, you can make a single argument that is a dynamic array. The you can query the size of the array inside the function.
2. You can declare default values for argument that you do not want to pass in.

   task test(string signal="", int tog1=-1, int tog2=-1, int tog3=-1);
   ...
   test("name2", 1,2); /argument tog3 will be -1

Answer (score 3):

First of all `argv` and `@ARGV` iterate arguments passed to the program, not to the function. Verilog implements similar functionality with `plusargs`. In other words, you can pass arguments started with `+` and use `plusargs` functions to scan for them. For example, if you call the simulation image as this

```
%> simv +HELLO
```

in Vreilog you can use something like the following

```
initial begin
  if ($test$plusargs("HELLO")) $display("Hello argument found.");
  ...
end
```

The standard defines 2 functions:

```
$test$plusargs ( string )
$value$plusargs ( user_string, variable )
```

Secondly, `c` does **not** allow you to traverse function arguments, unless you use `varargs` with `variadic` functions. `perl` does allow it, treating args as an array. `verilog` does **not** have any language feature to do it.

However, verilog defines a set of `pli` functions for interoperability with `c`. `vpi` interface has features allowing you to traverse arguments of the task and function (in 'c').